# CSS not rendering View in asp.net core Mvc application

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a simple view that uses a layout.  When the page runs, the layout text and the text from the view load just fine.  Yet, the css file that I have attached does not work

Comment: Please provide details about the problem.  In the browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, does the CSS file load?  What specific style rule and target HTML is failing to apply that style?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@RenderSection("heads", required: false)` in `<head></head>` of Shared/_layout.cshtml.And use `@section heads{}` in your view,add the css you want to your view.

Here is a demo worked:

Layout:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - case1_5_26_</title>
    @RenderSection("heads", required: false)
</head>
```

View:

```
@section heads{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
}
```

result:
[image]